# application not found with luis api version 3.0 preview

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I was testing the new preview 3.0 version for LUIS on the test console available at "https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-endpoint-api-v3-0-preview/operations/5cb0a9459a1fe8fa44c28dd8/console" .

Despite I am using the same key and app id that correctly work for version 2.0 I get as response the error message "The application wasn't found. Please make sure that the application is published to this region".

The ID for the application I inserted in the console form is published for westus region, the error message seems not truthful.

Anybody else is having the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: same here when I gave a quick try with an existing app

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in the documentation. Please try adding `/slot/{slotName}/` before the `predict` keyword, where `slotName` is either `staging` or `production`. So the url becomes:

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v3.0-preview/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/slots/{slotName}/predict?query={query}`

An example would be:

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v3.0-preview/apps/a1fc3658-a4c5-4fb2-88d3-69ba49e7abad/versions/0.1/slots/production/predict?query={query}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I added the /slot/production or /slot/staging part to the URL but this seems not to be enough for me.

After this change I get a 404 error as answer:

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 404,
        "message": "Resource not found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you (or can you) using the Get published slot predictions using the following:  https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-endpoint-api-v3-0-preview/operations/5cb0a91e54c9db63d589f433/console

Also, make sure that you have published to production or staging using the luis.ai UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature introduced in v3. We now allow publishing to the endpoint using the *version Id* instead of publishing to a slot. Since the version publishing isn't supported in the UI currently, you won't be able to publish to a version (yet). For now, use the publishing slot as Omar suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Below the working Request URL produced by the get published slot prediction console, available at https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-endpoint-api-v3-0-preview/operations/5cb0a91e54c9db63d589f433/console :

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v3.0-preview/apps/{APPID}/slots/Production/predict?query={QUERY}&verbose=true&log=true&show-all-intents=true
```

Thanks